# Query with Apollo in SSR and Dynamic URLs (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo

I'm developing a project that uses dynamic URLS like [slug].js what I'm trying to do is: when someone access some url like domain.com/my-post my page should query for available slugs (that contains data like SEO metatags) in a graphql endpoint and load the page if the url exists in my database.

I`m using SSR, apollo hooks and etc.

My question is: on production when someone share that url on facebook or things like that the metatags on that url (domain.com/my-post) will be the empty ones (before query looks for available slugs) or after the metatags and contents was full filled? considering that when I use useQuery from apollo I need to return something in order handle loading and error from that query. I'm some point when users access that url will show a "loading" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: on production when someone share that url on facebook
>   or things like that the metatags on that url (domain.com/my-post) will
>   be the empty ones (before query looks for available slugs) or after
>   the metatags and contents was full filled?

It depends on where you make the request for the slug.
If you make the request server side (ex. inside `getInitialProps`) pages will wait  to fetch data before pre-rendering, that means that when the page will render, it will render with metatags.

If you are following the with-apollo example it should [render server side](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/7bd4f4f3bf7696ab0da666105e2220447e1486ef/examples/with-apollo/lib/apollo.js#L45) obviously only if you are using your HOC in `pages` else if you are importing your HOC deeper in your component Tree, `getInitialProps` will be ignored (since it work only in pages)